# How to get the tail of `$^` in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rule in a Makefile

```
%/collapsed_flow_profile.png: \
code/piv/plot_collapsed_flow_profiles.R \
%/experiment2/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
%/experiment3/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
%/experiment4/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
%/experiment6/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
%/experiment7/averaged_flow_profile.csv
    code/piv/plot_collapsed_flow_profiles.R \
$*/collapsed_flow_profile.png \
$*/experiment2/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$*/experiment3/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$*/experiment4/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$*/experiment6/averaged_flow_profile.csv \
$*/experiment7/averaged_flow_profile.csv
```

As you can see, I'm passing all the dependencies except the first one as an argument to the code used in the recipe. Since `$^` automatic variable contains all the dependencies, it is possible to remove the first dependency from `$^` and pass it to the code as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `$(firstword a b c)` -> `a` and `$(filter-out ...)` and `$(wordlist s,e,text)` functions for transforming text. Combining them might be able to do what you want. The [excellent documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) has the details.

PS: What happened to experiment 5? Outlier? Does not fit expectations? :-)

Comment: Thanks for answer. In experiment 5, the microscope was out of focus from the middle layer (it can be clearly seen from the videos), so I had to discard it, as it would lead to faulty results.

Comment: If you know you always want to ignore the first word in `$^` then `wordlist` alone is sufficient.  The first prerequisite is always available in `$<` so you don't need `firstword` or `filter-out`, plus those operate on all words so they might give the wrong answer if the first word appears more than once in the list (unlikely in this situation of course).